# bash including file type switch using find command

Tags: bash, search, types, find, switch-statement

I use the find command a lot in bash. I normally keep it simple:

```
find . -name foo.txt
```

However I've noticed often the use of the type switch i.e. -type f, when the search is just for a text file.

Does including this switch speed up the search if you know the file being searched for is a txt file?

```
find -type f . -name foo.txt
```

Comment: I think that the answer to this question will depend on a number of factors, possibly including the filesystem and underlying OS. If you are using a Unix-based system, perhaps you would have more success asking over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The system is FreeBSD but I write my scripts using bash.

Answer (score 0):

> -type f … Does including this switch speed up the search if you know the file
>   being searched for is a txt file? … The system is FreeBSD …

No, since [`find`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/usr.bin/find) descends the directory tree evaluating    each file in the tree, the extra expression won't save time.